# Hadoop reduce method behaves in a way I cannot reason about

Tags: java, hadoop

I am trying to join together two files. This is my (redundant with debugging exceptions) reduce function:

```
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException,  InterruptedException {
        Text w1 = new Text();
        Text w2 = new Text();
        List<Text> arr = new ArrayList<Text>();
        List<Text> debugging = new ArrayList<Text>();
        long c_w1 = -1;
        for(Text value: values){
            debugging.add(value);
            try{
            StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
            if(str.countTokens() == 1){
                throw new Exception("special exception1. countTokens: "+str.countTokens() + " c_w1: " + c_w1);
                //context.write(key, value);
                //continue;
            }
            w1 = new Text(str.nextToken());
            w2 = new Text(str.nextToken());
            if(str.countTokens() == 1){ // c(w1)

                c_w1 = Long.parseLong(str.nextToken());
                continue;
            }
            else if(value.toString().contains(uniqueWord)){
                throw new Exception("special exception2. countTokens: "+str.countTokens() + " c_w1: " + c_w1);
            }
            else{ // an entire entry
                if(value.toString().contains(uniqueWord))
                    throw new Exception("special exception3. countTokens: "+str.countTokens() + " c_w1: " + c_w1);
                arr.add(value);
            }
            }catch(Exception e){
                throw new IOException("key: "+key.toString() +" value: "+value.toString()+" the last stacktrace: "+e.getMessage());
            }
        }
            for( Text value : arr){
                try{
                    if(value.toString().contains(uniqueWord))
                        throw new Exception("special exception4. arr length: " +arr.size()+ " c_w1: " + c_w1);
                    Text ans = new Text("w1:"+c_w1);
                    context.write(value, ans);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    throw new IOException("key: "+key.toString() +" value: "+value.toString()+" the last stacktrace: "+e.getMessage());
                }
            }
    }
```

I added all of these "spcial exceptions" in order to debug (Since System.out.println does'nt work when run on the cloud). The result:

> Error: java.io.IOException: key: N.T.O._NOUN value:
> N.T.O._NOUN   43uireoaugibghui4reagf  13 the last stacktrace: special
> exception4. arr length: 1 c_w1: 13    at
> JoinW1$ReducerClass.reduce(JoinW1.java:150)   at
> JoinW1$ReducerClass.reduce(JoinW1.java:1)     at
> org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:171)     at
> org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:635)
> at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:390)     at
> org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)  at
> java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
> javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)    at
> org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
> at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
> Blockquote
> Blockquote

If special exception4 is raised because value != uniqueWord, special exception3 should had been raised earlier!

Worth mentioning that `String unqiueWord = "43uireoaugibghui4reagf"` is a static, predefined variable.

The input im running the job on is these two files:

```
N.T.O._NOUN _NOUN_  1960's  13
nt  should_VERB 1960's  40
ntW _NOUN_  1960's  12
nt_NOUN as_ADP  1960's  53
nt_VERB ^_NUM   1960's  17
nterpretat  ion_NOUN    1960's  7
```

and

```
43uireoaugibghui4reagf  ^_NUM   17
43uireoaugibghui4reagf  _NOUN_  25
43uireoaugibghui4reagf  as_ADP  53
43uireoaugibghui4reagf  ion_NOUN    7
43uireoaugibghui4reagf  should_VERB 40
N.T.O._NOUN 43uireoaugibghui4reagf  13
nt  43uireoaugibghui4reagf  40
ntW 43uireoaugibghui4reagf  12
nt_NOUN 43uireoaugibghui4reagf  53
nt_VERB 43uireoaugibghui4reagf  17
nterpretat  43uireoaugibghui4reagf  7
```

where the result should be joining together lines that have the same first word, taking the entire tuple of the first file and the last number of the second file to form a new tuple.
Example:
`ntW    _NOUN_  1960's  12`                                                              and `ntW   43uireoaugibghui4reagf  12` would result in:

```
ntW _NOUN_  1960's  12 w1:12
```